# Wildcard redirect from subdomain root folder to subdomain subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

So I recently sorted all my files on a subdomain into different folders, let's just call it `upload.example.org`. One of the new folders is titled "img" (`public_html/upload/img`), where I now automatically upload any pictures I take for easy sharing. Previously all images were in the document root folder "upload" and that's where I used to share the URLs from, so a redirect to the new URL is needed to avoid breaking anything.

Now what I've been trying to do is create a .htaccess that redirects people from `upload.example.org/image.jpg` to `upload.example.org/img/image.jpg`. `image.jpg` can be replaced with any other file name in the img folder.

**Looking for answers, I found this:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Using this line of code with my subdomain results in a loop, in the end redirecting me to `http://upload.example.org/img/img/img/img/img/img/img/img/img/img/image.jpg`.

After searching and trying out different .htaccess variants, I couldn't come across the correct solution.

Any help that you can give would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the loop is because after the redirect, the client requests the new URL and this new URL is redirected again, causing a new request from the client and again a redirect, and so on ...

To avoid this, you must prefix the rule with a stop condition, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^img/ - [L]
```

This causes an exit to the rewrite chain, if the requested URL already starts with `img/`.

---

Another approach would be to test first if an appropriate file exists in the `img` folder, and only redirect if there is one.

```
RewriteCond /img/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^img/$1 [R,L]
```

---

If you want to exclude a folder from any rewrite, use a stop condition rule as in the above example

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/some/folder - [L]
```

This ensures, that any request beginning with the given URL path is  ever rewritten or redirected.

If you want an exception from only the `img` rule, you could add another condition to the rule, which checks if the resulting path would be in this other folder, e.g.

```
RewriteCond /img/$1 -f
RewriteCond /img/excluded/folder/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^img/$1 [R,L]
```

These conditions check first, if the image exists somewhere in the `img` subfolder, and then make sure it is not a file in the `img/excluded/folder`.

---

Unrelated, but *never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)! When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. One last request, could you show me how the full .htaccess has to look like then?

Comment: You can either put the first `RewriteRule` in front of your other rules. Or if you want to try the second rule instead, replace the existing `RewriteRule` with the `RewriteCond/RewriteRule` pair.

Comment: These rules only work, if the .htaccess is in the `upload` folder. When the .htaccess is in the root directory, you must replace `img` with `upload/img` of course.